# Do ArrayLists that contain different types of objects use different amounts of memory?

Tags: java, memory, arraylist

For example, if you were to have

```
    int a=2; int b=3;
    ArrayList<Integer>integers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    integers.add(a); integers.add(b);
```

and

```
    String c="cow"; String d="deer";
    ArrayList<String> strings= new ArrayList<String>();
    strings.add(c); strings.add(d);
```

Would they take different amounts of memory? Any help/answer would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your second example lacked the generic parameter...

Comment: Does a shopping list for 100 soccer balls take more paper than the shopping list for 100 golf balls?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The ArrayLists themselves are nothing more than a collection of references, and these take the same amount of memory (if the same size) no matter the type of objects they hold. However the items referred to by the ArrayList all take differing amounts of memory as you would expect.

Answer (score 10):

ArrayLists are nothing but a collection of references, so the size of ArrayList does not depends on the type of the object it points to. Hence the memory of the ArrayList does not depend on the reference object types.

Answer (score 7):

In your case, and in theory, they would consume the same amount of memory, in runtime generics "doesn't exist" and both arrays are actually arrays of objects.

Comment: ... therefore all objects use the same amount of memory. 1 = 0!

Comment: @Thomas The question is about the Array, not the objects it refers to, is is incorrect to consider that the array "contains" other objects

Comment: @morgano actually, they are arrays of references to Objects. A Foo[] takes exactly the same space as a Bar[] of the same size. Only the objects themselves differ in size, not the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList<Foo>(10);
```

arr contains just 1 reference of the backing array. This backing array will have 10 references of 10 different Foo Objects in heap.

Comment: You are confusing arrays with `ArrayList`s. Just using the `int` constructor doesn't cause the list to contain anything. It is just the initial capacity. The `ArrayList` uses an array internally. The initial capacity just defines the size of this array. `<Foo>` is just for type safety (read generics).

Answer (score -1):

ArrayList is an object like String or smth else. It stores collection in an internal Object[] array. These arrays will take different amount if memory but ArrayList themselves will be the same size.